# How do I highlight syntax errors using ICSharpCode.TextEditor.TextEditorControl?

Tags: sharpdevelop, icsharpcode

I'm using `ICSharpCode.TextEditor.TextEditorControl` as my DSL editor.  When I get DSL compilation errors, I would like to highlight the offending text to provide a better user experience.  However, I'm having difficulty finding how to do this.

So far, I've found that there is a `ShowInvalidLines` property but I don't see a way to mark any lines as invalid.  I also see `HighlightSpanStack` property of `LineSegment` and `HighlightingStrategy` but not sure how they are supposed to be used.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To highlight a piece of text use a TextMarker. The following code underlines the word Error with a red wavy line.

```
TextEditorControl textEditor = new TextEditorControl();
textEditor.Text = "Mark Error";

int offset = 5;
int length = 5;
TextMarker marker = new TextMarker(offset, length, TextMarkerType.WaveLine, Color.Red);
textEditor.Document.MarkerStrategy.AddMarker(marker);
```

You can highlight the text with any background and foreground colour and the TextMarkerType supports underlining, wavy lines or a solid block of colour.

Comment: doesnt work on latest 4.4.2 version, would be good if someone could update the syntax. for example, MarketStragety is no more

Comment: The last version released of the ICSharpCode.TextEditor was 3.2.1.6466. This question refers to the older ICSharpCode.TextEditor control. AvalonEdit, which is the newer text editor included with SharpDevelop, has a version 4.4.2. AvalonEdit was re-written to support WPF and has a very different API.

Comment: I had to put a Refresh() to force the control to redraw. But once I did that, I could see my multiple highlights just fine.